# CSS offset undefined for a text floating div

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Given :

```js
const display = document.querySelector('.display');

document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (!event.target.closest("button")) return;
  
  if(event.target.id === "button") {

    if(event.target.textContent === "left"){
        display.style.transform += "translateX(50px)";
    } else if (event.target.textContent === "right"){
        display.style.transform += "translateX(-50px)";
    }
    console.log("left :" + display.style.offsetLeft + ", right : " + display.style.offsetRight);
    console.log("left :" + display.parentNode.style.offsetLeft + ", right : " + display.parentNode.style.offsetRight);
  }
    
});
```

```css
.meta-div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden; /* allows the border-radius to be visible. */
  width: 14rem;
}
.outer-div {
  color: black;
  text-overflow: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  border-left: 30px solid black;
  border-right: 30px solid black;

}

.display {
  float:right;
  padding-right: 5px;
  transition: transform 250ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="meta-div">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="display">111 + 222 + 333 + 444 + 555 + 666 + 777 + 888 + 999</div>
  </div>
</div>
 <button id="button">left</button>
 <button id="button">right</button>
```

my goal is to find a way to extract the display's text position relative to its container (which I set to `relative` for `offsetLeft` to work), such that the left/right buttons don't work when the text has reached the respective left or right maximal position. Basically, I want the text to minimally start at "111 + ..." or maximally end at "... + 999".

In other words, I want to set a limit to the `display.style.transform += "translateX(50px)";` function call both from the left and from the right.

---

Looking online the solution seems to be to use `offset`. In my case, the offset seems to be `undefined` in both directions for both the `display` text element and its parent container. Could this be because of the `float:right` property?  I am short of ideas on how to implement this small feature. I suspect I may not even be using the right function at all (offset) ?

Does anyone have any tips or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is that, the attribute that should be used is `display.offsetLeft` and `display.offsetTop`. You are currently using `display.style.offsetLeft.`
Apart from that, there is no attribute called offsetRight. If you want to do that, you will have to calculate it yourself.

Hence your code can be rewritten like so:

```
const display = document.querySelector('.display');

document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (!event.target.closest("button")) return;
  
  if(event.target.id === "button") {

    if(event.target.textContent === "left"){
        display.style.transform += "translateX(50px)";
    } else if (event.target.textContent === "right"){
        display.style.transform += "translateX(-50px)";
    }
    console.log("left :" + display.offsetLeft);
    
  }
    
});
```

Apart from this, you could also use the getBoundingClientRect() function, and then calculate the difference in the offsets between the parent and the child elements. But since, I don't know the use case, I could be wrong about this. getBoundingClientRect can be used as follows though:

```
const display = document.querySelector('.display');
const container = document.querySelector('.outer-div');


document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (!event.target.closest("button")) return;
  
  
  const eleRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  const targetRect = display.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  if(event.target.id === "button") {

    if(event.target.textContent === "left"){
        display.style.transform += "translateX(50px)";
    } else if (event.target.textContent === "right"){
        display.style.transform += "translateX(-50px)";
    }
    
    // Calculate the top and left positions
    const top = eleRect.top - targetRect.top;
    const left = eleRect.left - targetRect.left;
    
    console.log("left :" + left); 

  }
    
});
```